# where do u save a gif file in android eclipse?

Tags: android, gif

I've animated a gif and i have no idea how to reference it in my android application such that it plays the gif over and over.As well as which res folder to save it in.

Comment: store it in assets folder and add WebView to your xml and load the gif image inside the webview

Comment: here is an nice tutorial how to handle it. You can put the gifs in the drawable folder. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uRI4PuxDuqg